# Reverse sign function returns none

Tags: python

I would like to create a function where one passes a list of numbers and gets back another list where the signs of all numbers are reversed. This is my code:

```
def reverse_sign_of_nos_in_a_list(list1):
    """ This function reverses sign of numbers
        in a list and returns a list.
    """
    list2 = []
    for num in list1 :
        if num > 0 :
            return list2.append(num * -1)
        elif num < 0 :
            return list2.append(abs(num))
        else :
            return list2.append(num)

print (reverse_sign_of_nos_in_a_list([1,2,3,-1,-2,-3,0]))
```

The above code shows `None` as the output. What's the issue?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stack overflow.
Keep the title matching with your issue/problem/question, and not with your assigned task or goal.
This makes easy the search and helps others after.

Answer (score 4):

The are a couple of things wrong with your code:

1. You have a return statement in every branch of your code. That means that you will return from the first iteration of the loop no matter what.
2. `list.append` modifies the target instance in place. As is conventional in Python for such methods, it returns None, which, combined with #1 means that you always get a return value of None.

There's also something very strange about your code. You flip the sign of a positive number by multiplying by -1. That makes sense. But then you take the absolute value of a negative number. Why? Flipping the sign is the same as multiplying by -1 for negative numbers too. And even for zero.

In fact, you don't even need to multiply by -1. There's already a "flip the sign" operator: unary `-`.

You can write your function as a single list comprehension:

```
def reverse_sign_of_nos_in_a_list(list1):
    return [-x for x in list1]
```

Answer (score 1):

`reverse_sign_of_nos_in_a_list` is returning `None` because `list.append()` returns `None`, not **appended list**.

Following should do the job:

```
def reverse_sign_of_nos_in_a_list(list1) :
    """ This function reverses sign of numbers
        in a list and returns a list.
    """
    list2 = []
    for num in list1 :
        if num > 0 :
            list2.append(num * -1)
        elif num < 0 :
            list2.append(abs(num))
        else :
            list2.append(num)
    return list2
```

Comment: The code is correct, but your explanation is not.

Comment: @MadPhysicist You are right. Let me make some edits

Answer (score 1):

`list.append()` method will append the new element in-place and then will return `None`. So your function returns that `None`. Also it will return immediatelly after first element of the original list is processed.

```
def reverse_sign_of_nos_in_a_list(list1):
    """ This function reverses sign of numbers
        in a list and returns a list.
    """
    list2 = []
    for num in list1:
        if num > 0:
            list2.append(num * -1)
        elif num < 0:
            list2.append(abs(num))
        else:
            list2.append(num)
    return list2

print(reverse_sign_of_nos_in_a_list([1,2,3,-1,-2,-3,0]))
```

Please, note I keep the code as close as possible to the original code. I would implement the function differently.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append and then return the list.

```
list2.append(...)
return list2
```

The reason you are getting `None` as output is because `append` is a void-Method that does not return a value. It only alters list2.

Answer (score 0):

Because list.append(elem) -- adds a single element to the end of the list. Common error: does not return the new list, just modifies the original

You should use similar to:

```
def reverse_sign_of_nos_in_a_list(list1) :
    """ This function reverses sign of numbers
        in a list and returns a list.
    """
    list2 = []
    for num in list1 :
        if num > 0 :
            list2.append(-num)
        elif num < 0 :
            list2.append(abs(num))
        else:
            list2.append(num)
    return list2

print(reverse_sign_of_nos_in_a_list([1,2,3,-1,-2,-3,0]))
```

Comment: More to the point, it returns None

Comment: Have made some tabulation in the latest line.

Comment: I was referring to "just modifies the original". It also returns None.

Answer (score 0):

If you want every element of your list reversed, you should remove all the return which cause the function to return prematurely.

### Code

```
def reverse_sign_of_nos_in_a_list(list1) :
    """ This function reverses sign of numbers
        in a list and returns a list.
    """
    list2 = []
    for num in list1 :
        if num > 0 :
            list2.append(num * -1)
        elif num < 0 :
            list2.append(abs(num))
        else :
            list2.append(num)
    return list2

print (reverse_sign_of_nos_in_a_list([1,2,3,-1,-2,-3,0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

A different, shorter (and kind of more pythonic) way for the whole thing:

```
def reverse_sign_of_nos_in_a_list(list1):
    return [(-1)*ii for ii in list1]
```